# Matrix reconstruction puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, svd, singular-values

Say a reconstruction of matrix $A$ is $A'$  and it's defined as

$ A' = P^TDPA $

where $P$ is an orthonormal matrix, $D$ is a diagonal binary (1 or 0) matrix. In a trivial case, when all diagonal elements are 1, we have a perfect reconstruction ($A'=A$).

Now we constrain the number of 1's in the diagonal entries of $D$ to, say, $n$. How do I find the best $D$ s.t. $Tr(D)=n$ that would minimize $||A-A'||$?

I think I need to inspect the singular vectors of $A$, but I am not sure what to do exactly.

Comment: Let $P^\top D P = B$, then $A' = BA$. finally, $rank(A') = rank(BA)\leq min(rank(B),rank(A))$. We also observe that $rank(B) \leq rank(D)= Tr(D)$ therefore $rank(A')\leq Tr(D)$. Question: Is the optimization problem over D alone? ie. are P and A fixed, and $A'$ varying depending on D?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan yes, we are basically only permuting the diagonal elements of D. P and A are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D = argmin_{D\in\text{binary diag}}\quad ||P^\top DPA - A||$
Now let's change basis for A using $P$ (which is orthonormal). Thus $\exists M$ such $A = P^\top MP$. Note that M is deterministic as we know $P$ and $A$.

Making this substitution in the first equation, we get
\begin{align*}
D &= argmin_{D\in\text{binary diag}}\quad ||P^\top DPP^\top MP - P^\top MP||\\
&= argmin_{D\in\text{binary diag}}\quad ||P^\top D MP - P^\top MP||\\
&= argmin_{D\in\text{binary diag}}\quad ||P^\top (D M-M) P||\\
\end{align*}
Now comes the crucial part, since P is orthonormal (equivalent to original basis), this optimization problem is the same as:
\begin{align*}
D &= argmin_{D\in\text{binary diag}}\quad ||D M-M||\\
&= argmin_{D\in\text{binary diag}}\quad ||(D-I) M||\\
\end{align*}

Thus, we choose D such that the 1's correspond to the maximum norm rows of $M$